# How to check if User is inside the VPN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, networking, web, vpn

Is there a way to find out if a web user is inside the company VPN?? i need to check automatically if the user is inside the company VPN. Is there a way to do this throgh a website?

I know i can't use java-script to ping some service inside VPN, because i can't ping to a service outside of the current domain for browser security reasons.

So, how can i automatically check if the user is inside the VPN using a Web Page?

EDIT: is it possible to use an image tag to try to load an image form a server inside the VPN? If the image does not load, it means the user is not in the VPN. Is this suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It so many Methods to be a vpn, so it is hard to tell a way to differentiate it.

**I suggest you can set a independent subnet for VPN and VPN users** that check the client IP, and you will sure if they came from VPN or not.

It's in common use I think. try :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am afraid i can't configure anything related to the VPN. I have to deal with the current configuration. Could it be possible to place an "<img>" tag in my website pointing to a file in a server inside VPN? If the image does not load, it means it's outside the VPN.  could this work?

Comment: @Herno did it works for you? How can you do it? If you want, you can answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536444/check-availibility-of-an-url-with-https-and-json